# Smart Network Data Service reports spam from my IP. Nothing in my logs

Tags: spam

I am facing a very strange situation.
Microsoft's Smart Network Data Service is reporting that my IP is attempting to send hundreds of thousands of spams to Microsoft accounts every day.

[image: SNDS report]

But, checking my server's logs I have found no indications of that kind of sending volume.

My **Qmail queue is 0**

**None** of the recipient email address mentioned in the SNDS report is found in my logs.

**No malicious** or suspicious script is running on my server

For example, in the sample spam message that I've got from SNDS it mentions "X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1249:phoned.php".
No such file is present on my server!!!

So how is this possible?

Comment: Could you have a rogue SMTP server on your network?

Comment: It's because one or more of your web sites was hacked. It's time to respond to it as the breach event that it is.